# How do I automatically code integer variables as factors?

Tags: r, regression, lm, categorical-data, r-factor

I'm dealing with predictors that I'd like to treat as factors. Unfortunately, the data, which represent answers to multiple choice questions, are stored as integers, and so when I fit a linear model, R treats these as numeric predictors rather than factors. I do not want to type out `factor(x)` every time; how would I automatically code the predictors as factor variables?

Example of data that I might have:

```
  a b response
1 1 T 6.946486
2 2 F 1.952378
3 3 T 5.189918
4 1 T 2.680438
5 2 F 2.243461
6 3 T 5.398814
7 1 T 2.375182
8 2 F 0.376323
9 3 T 5.144803
```

Desired task: tell R without having to type out `lm(response ~ factor(a) + b)` that predictor `a` should be treated as a factor variable. Maybe I need to iterate through each column and save as a factor, and then pass to `lm`? Maybe there is something I can pass to `lm`? Trying different things...

Comment: `data$a <- as.factor(data$a); lm(response ~ a + b, data = data)` ?...which is actually more typing and now you've changed your entire data set.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It may be the simplest to convert all answers to multiple choice questions (MCQs) to factors before passing the data frame to `lm`. Assuming that all integer variables are MSQ answers, you can use `is.integer` and `sapply`:

```
## making up data
N <- 20
d <- data.frame(a = sample(3, N, replace=TRUE),
                b = sample(3, N, replace=TRUE),
                c = sample(3, N, replace=TRUE),
                d = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace=TRUE),
                e = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace=TRUE),
                f = sample(3, N, replace=TRUE),
                response = rnorm(20, 0, 2))

## determine which columns are integer
int_col <- which(sapply(d, is.integer))

## convert all integer variables to factor variables
d[, int_col] <- lapply(d[int_col], factor) # sapply doesn't work here
str(d)
```

If you have integer variables that are not MSQ answers, then you'll have to modify `int_col` manually, excluding those variables.